# Pre-selecting a dropdown list item in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to update a pre-existing property on an object via a dropdown list. The solution used knockout and ko.mapping frameworks to get its data. The issue I'm having is selecting the item in the list that the existing object has already set.

For example: If a dropdown list contains 2 options, lets say first male and second female, and the property it represents is already set to female, I want the dropdown to have female selected. But the dropdown list is defaulting to the first item in the list (male) and updating the underlying object to male.

I've knocked up a quick example of the above, I have mocked up the data to match what i am dealing with ie json from server getting mapped using ko.mapping framework.

**viewmodel**

```
var listItems = '[{"id": "1","name": "male"},{"id": "2","name": "female"}]';
var savedRecord = '{"gender": {"id": "2","name": "female"}}';

ViewModel = function () {
    mappedListItems = ko.mapping.fromJSON(listItems);
    mappedSavedRecord = ko.mapping.fromJSON(savedRecord);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**html**

```
<select data-bind="options: mappedListItems, 
               optionsText: 'name',                    
               value: mappedSavedRecord.gender"></select>
<p>mappedSavedRecord.gender.name = <span data-bind="text: mappedSavedRecord.gender.name"></span>
```

**JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/tgriley1/tLHhE/

Comment: You don't need to specify the `optionsValue` so you can have complex objects in your select, you just need to setup your mappedSavedRecord differently http://jsfiddle.net/xgKvx/1/. KO compares complex object by reference so your `mappedSavedRecord` should contain an actual item from `mappedListItems`. It is not enough that the id and gender are the same...

Comment: @nemesv Funnily enough I had tried that approach, but as the object that contains the gender property has much more going on around it I just wanted to set the gender property, which for some reason I couldn't work out. see fiddle for example http://jsfiddle.net/tgriley1/9nzr4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not told Knockout which field to use for the value attribute in the dropdown, and you've also not told it which field on your saved record to use to pre-select an option:

```
<select data-bind="options: mappedListItems, 
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsValue: 'id',                                      
                   value: mappedSavedRecord.gender.id"></select>
```

Comment: Ok cool thats great, I had tried setting the optionsValue but had left the value as the whole gender object. So a select binding can bind too an array of objects but can only output a single value, not the entire object each object represents?

Comment: @tom I don't understand how you missed this.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. You can bind an object to it, but you need to tell it which property to use for the options value and which to use for the options text. If you want an option pre-selected, you need to tell it which value you want it to compare against.

Comment: @Boss That's a bit harsh, I'm sure we've all produced code that missed something out when we start using a new tech/framework.

Comment: @paul I don't know how to express it.I agree every one make mistakes.But still he is expecting to get entire object as value. He doesn't check his output in firebug  that the option value is empty.

Comment: @paul hope you understand what I said.

Comment: I had tried setting the optionsValue to id, but id left value as mappedSavedRecord.gender and had the markup spit out the gender name value which made me think it wasnt updating, when infact it was updating the Id on the gender object alone, not the whole thing. I've updated my jsfiddle to represent this. http://jsfiddle.net/tgriley1/tLHhE/

Comment: @Boss Sure, but when something starts going wrong, it's easy to change so much that multiple parts of it are wrong, so I wouldn't be too harsh. I know I've done the same thing. Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it's now working for you.

Comment: @Boss I don't think it is unreasonable to assume when binding an array of objects to a dropdown list that each option represents the entire source object, not just a single property. My incorrect assumption had resulted in me thinking I could output the entire object as the value, when infact, it will only output the nominated property. I had missed this because I was monitoring the name of underlying object i was trying to modify, but as the value coming out was only the Id and not the whole object, the name would remain the unchanged. See fiddle for an example.

Comment: @tom I apologize if I hurt-ed you.I am not good in English that's the reason behind.